# Change element's oninput event using a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the oninput event for an input field to the input event specified in a variable.

Right now, I have

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
var tofunction = "alert('test');";
input.oninput = function oninput(event) { tofunction };
document.getElementById('div').append(input);
```

When inputting in the text box, nothing happens, but if I set it manually without a variable it performs the function defined.

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.oninput = function oninput(event) { alert('test'); };
document.getElementById('div').append(input);
```

Comment: Because `"alert('test');"` with quotation marks around it is not a function, it's just a string. You could do `var tofunction = function() { alert('test'); }`. You now have a function named `tofunction` that will alert when called. If you want that to happen on input, try `input.oninput = tofunction`.

Comment: No. You don't want this. Trust me. But since you won't, `var oninput = new Function(tofunction)`.

Comment: @JaredSmith ...maybe he would trust you if you explained in the slightest *why* you were saying that.

Comment: There's always `eval()` but notice how close it is to `evil`...

Comment: @JaredSmith 's answer worked, Thanks!

Comment: @NathanMetzger Note that Jared was trying to warn you to **not do that**. There is **rarely ever** a reason to turn strings into executable code. If that string is coming from a user, then you should **absolutely not do this**. Please consider expanding your question to explain *why* you want this before implementing it, for your own sake.

Comment: @TylerRoper if I thought I could explain everything involved in that request in the space of a comment, I would. If I thought I could answer the question (explaining all of the various problems) in the space of an answer, I'd do that too. You did the right thing to ask for more info to hopefully narrow it down.

Comment: @TylerRoper it's for personal use, I don't care about injection vulnerabilities, thanks for letting me know though